# How to exit DAG as normal without other tasks execution in AirFlow

Tags: airflow

Is there a way to exit Dag as normal without executing subsequent tasks?
For example, I make sequent tasks like "taskA >> taskB >> taskC", and if something condition are met in taskA, I want to terminate its DAG as normal end without subsequent tasks execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, try [ShortCircuitOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/python/index.html#airflow.operators.python.ShortCircuitOperator)

ShortCircuitOperator allows a workflow to continue only if a condition is met. Otherwise, the workflow “short-circuits” and downstream tasks are skipped.

In order to determine the following tasks need to execute or not, pass the condition to python_callable with ShortCircuitOperator.